# Translate MS SQL Server performance queries to MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-migration, query-performance

I am trying to calculate some performance metrics for a number of SQL queries. I have found the benchmarking queries for MS SQL Server and I would like the same queries for MySQL Workbench (Windows environment). The queries I am using are the following:

```
--Elapsed time and CPU time
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
   Query to measure
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF;

-- RAM
select
(physical_memory_in_use_kb)Phy_Memory_usedby_Sqlserver_KB,
(virtual_address_space_committed_kb/1024 )Total_Memory_UsedBySQLServer_MB
from sys. dm_os_process_memory

--HD
sp_msforeachtable N'EXEC sp_spaceused [?]';
```

Could you please help me to convert the above queries to MySQL?
I would not like to use the reports provided by the Performance Schema of MySQL Workbench since I want to compare the results with the above queries of MS SQL Server.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just to clarify, these queries use SQL Server system tables that aren't defined in any sort of ANSI standard, so there isn't going to be a clean way to translate them for another RDBMS that's perfectly comparable. I'd just google around for how to measure query time, RAM, and disk space on MySQL, and not worry so much about finding a perfect analog to SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

As Jeff pointed out, you can't get exactly those features in MySQL.  Nor can you even get close.  But, here are some useful things:

- Turn on the slowlog with `long_quer_time` set to 0.  Then look in the slowlog for a variety of information about the query.
- Use `performance_schema` (which needs "turning on")
- For simple timing, either do it in the client, or do

  ```
  SELECT SYSDATE(6), ..., SYSDATE(6) FROM ...;
  ```
- Memory for a specific query is not available.  (However, MariaDB has something like that.)  Usually a query takes a relatively fixed, and small, amount of memory.  Most of what it uses is shared -- various caches.
- `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`
- `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`
- Optimizer trace.  This needs to be "turned on", and you need to fetch the results.